# Find the largest cube that can be inscribed in this ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, ellipsoids

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Using Lagrange multipliers, find the largest cube (with faces parallel to the coordinate axes) that can be inscribed in the ellipsoid $$x^2 + \frac14 y^2 + \frac19 z^2 = 1$$

---

I got an answer of 1728/343, but I'm pretty sure this is not right. Basically, since it's a cube I put f(x,y,z) = xyz = x^3 and then put x^2 + (y^2)/4 + (z^2)/9 = 1 in terms of x to get (49x^2)/36 = 1 to get that the vertices of the cube are where x,y,z = ±6/7, hence the volume will be (12/7)^3 = 1728/343, but this just does not seem right to me. Is this right, and if not, how do I solve this?

Comment: Which optimization problem did you solve?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).